# Multiple IF Statements under a Parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

**Introduction**

I've been tasked with creating a user management PowerShell script to be used for one of our customers so that we can easily manage users and automate a lot of our user creation processes.

---

**The Issue**

Our customer is insisting on using login scripts over GPO for mapping drives for users. I have added a login script builder to the script, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify which drives actually need adding to the login script.

---

**How Drive Mappings Are Managed**

The way drive mappings are managed at our customer's network, is based on job role + Active Directory groups. They request on an E-Form which drives need to be mapped, and we then look through the Active Directory to see which group has permissions to access the requested drives. We then add these groups.

---

**What I Need Help With**

The way that I've decided to manage this is to have multiple IF Statements under the parameter '$Drives'. I'm not sure how I would do this. The reason I want to do it this way, is so that when it writes the output to the login script, I only need to add one '$Drives' to the output.

---

**Current Code**

*Note: This may not all be in order, there may be code in-between on the actual script. This is just relevant code.*

```
$NewName = $SAMAccountName
$extension = ".bat"
$FileName = "$SAMAccountName$extension"
$ScriptDrive = "\\IPRemoved\scripts"
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $SAMAccountName | select name

$Drives = if ($Groups -contains 'Blah Blah Blah') {
    Write-Output "Net Use N: "\\FILE0\DRIVE""
} else {
    Write-Output ""
}

Write-Output "NET TIME \\FILE0 /SET /Y

$Drives

@echo off
REM -------------------------------
REM -- LANDesk v8.6.1 Installation --
REM -------------------------------
%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk\iDeploy.exe /F=%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk" `n`n|FT -AutoSize >>LoginScript.txt

Get-ChildItem LoginScript.txt | Rename-Item -NewName $FileName
Move-Item -Path ".\$FileName" -Destination $ScriptDrive
```

Comment: I dont really get how this differs to the question you asked yesterday / or what specific is you probleme here. An expected output would be nice.

Comment: @Paxz Yesterday I was asking for the specific method. Today I have the method, just not too sure if it is correct, and how I would run multiple Drives based on Group.

Example Output:

$drives would need to output Net use N: "\\FILE0\DRIVE1" then a line break Net use D: "\\FILE0\DRIVE2"

Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to put more than one drive in to the variable, so my solution is looping trough all of the group names in $Groups and adding them to an array for later use:

We could use normal arrays here like this $Drives = @()  but from a performance perspective
the System.Collections.ArrayList is using less memory and is a lot faster.
The | Out-Null part is needed to prevent the index output of the add method.
`$Drives = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`

Now just loop trough all the groups and add them to the $Drives array in order to use the variable later on.

```
foreach($Group in $Groups){
    switch($group){
        "Blah Blah Blah"{ $Drives.add("Net Use A: `"\\FILE1\DRIVE`"" | Out-Null)}
        "Bluh Bluh Bluh"{ $Drives.add("Net Use U: `"\\FILE2\DRIVE`"" | Out-Null)}
        "Bleh Bleh Bleh"{ $Drives.add("Net Use E: `"\\FILE3\DRIVE`"" | Out-Null)}
        default{ Write-Host "Group not found"}
    }

}
```

When you got all the drives you need stored in $Drives you can just write them to a file or append them to an existing one.

To a new file:
`$Drives | Out-File -FilePath "C:\path\file.txt"`

To append the data:
`$Drives | Out-File -FilePath "C:\path\file.txt" -Append`

Comment: Not what you need?